# docs_mail_merg Request for Access Issue

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-docs-api, mailmerge

Please review my [Git Hub response](https://github.com/googleworkspace/python-samples/issues/810). I have also attached my Python code to this post.

```
from __future__ import print_function

import time

from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

from google.oauth2 import service_account

# Set your credentials file path
credentials_path = '/Users/baker/Desktop/a3/credentials.json'

# Set your template document ID
template_document_id = '12g6okE4Hvr5VCMiGo6Z7szNSp_cZIRafdLHafGdEtRs'

# Set your Google Sheets document ID
spreadsheet_id = '1uzt7TxPSzJkcts6RIJv36KCD8IstYa2UAve8DKe2UZs'

# Set the sheet name in the Google Sheets document
sheet_name = 'Sheet1'

# Load credentials from the JSON file
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    credentials_path,
    scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
)

# Fill-in IDs of your Docs template & any Sheets data source
DOCS_FILE_ID = "12g6okE4Hvr5VCMiGo6Z7szNSp_cZIRafdLHafGdEtRs"
SHEETS_FILE_ID = "1uzt7TxPSzJkcts6RIJv36KCD8IstYa2UAve8DKe2UZs"

# Set the folder ID in Google Drive to save the merged documents
folder_id = '1Wknll1g5MiJSaVKtS2e-AHlL8EzeT6UG'

# application constants
SOURCES = ('text', 'sheets')
SOURCE = 'sheets'  # Choose one of the data SOURCES
COLUMNS = ['to_name', 'to_title', 'to_company', 'to_address']
TEXT_SOURCE_DATA = (
    ('Ms. Lara Brown', 'Googler', 'Google NYC', '111 8th Ave\n'
                                                'New York, NY  10011-5201'),
    ('Mr. Jeff Erson', 'Googler', 'Google NYC', '76 9th Ave\n'
                                                'New York, NY  10011-4962'),
)


# Build the Google Docs and Google Sheets services
DRIVE = build('drive', 'v2', credentials=credentials)
DOCS = build('docs', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
SHEETS = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)

def get_data(source):
    """Gets mail merge data from chosen data source.
    """
    try:
        if source not in {'sheets', 'text'}:
            raise ValueError(f"ERROR: unsupported source {source}; "
                             f"choose from {SOURCES}")
        return SAFE_DISPATCH[source]()
    except HttpError as error:
        print(f"An error occurred: {error}")
        return error

def _get_text_data():
    """(private) Returns plain text data; can alter to read from CSV file.
    """
    return TEXT_SOURCE_DATA

def _get_sheets_data(service=SHEETS):
    """(private) Returns data from Google Sheets source. It gets all rows of
        'Sheet1' (the default Sheet in a new spreadsheet), but drops the first
        (header) row. Use any desired data range (in standard A1 notation).
    """
    return service.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId=SHEETS_FILE_ID,
                                               range='Sheet1').execute().get(
        'values')[1:]
    # skip header row

# data source dispatch table [better alternative vs. eval()]
SAFE_DISPATCH = {k: globals().get('_get_%s_data' % k) for k in SOURCES}

def _copy_template(tmpl_id, source, service):
    """(private) Copies letter template document using Drive API then
        returns file ID of (new) copy.
    """
    try:
        body = {'name': 'Merged form letter (%s)' % source}
        return service.files().copy(body=body, fileId=tmpl_id,
                                    fields='id').execute().get('id')
    except HttpError as error:
        print(f"An error occurred: {error}")
        return error

def merge_template(tmpl_id, source, service):
    """Copies template document and merges data into newly-minted copy then
        returns its file ID.
    """
    try:
        # copy template and set context data struct for merging template values
        copy_id = _copy_template(tmpl_id, source, service)
        context = merge.iteritems() if hasattr({},
                                               'iteritems') else merge.items()

        # "search & replace" API requests for mail merge substitutions
        reqs = [{'replaceAllText': {
            'containsText': {
                'text': '{{%s}}' % key.upper(),  # {{VARS}} are uppercase
                'matchCase': True,
            },
            'replaceText': value,
        }} for key, value in context]

        # send requests to Docs API to do actual merge
        DOCS.documents().batchUpdate(body={'requests': reqs},
                                     documentId=copy_id, fields='').execute()
        return copy_id
    except HttpError as error:
        print(f"An error occurred: {error}")
        return error

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # fill-in your data to merge into document template variables
    merge = {
        # sender data
        'my_name': 'Ayme A. Coder',
        'my_address': '1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy\n'
                      'Mountain View, CA  94043-1351',
        'my_email': 'http://google.com',
        'my_phone': '+1-650-253-0000',
        # - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
        # recipient data (supplied by 'text' or 'sheets' data source)
        'to_name': None,
        'to_title': None,
        'to_company': None,
        'to_address': None,
        # - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
        'date': time.strftime('%Y %B %d'),
        # - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
        'body': 'Google, headquartered in Mountain View, unveiled the new '
                'Android phone at the Consumer Electronics Show. CEO Sundar '
                'Pichai said in his keynote that users love their new phones.'
    }

    # get row data, then loop through & process each form letter
    data = get_data(SOURCE)  # get data from data source
    for i, row in enumerate(data):
        merge.update(dict(zip(COLUMNS, row)))
        print('Merged letter %d: docs.google.com/document/d/%s/edit' % (
            i + 1, merge_template(DOCS_FILE_ID, SOURCE, DRIVE)))
```

Expected Behavior

access to links Produced ( i.e. for the links not to ask for access and direct to the produced docs for me to access) and for the resultant mail merge files to be deposited in my folders.

Actual Behavior

```
Receive the following message:

Merged letter 1: docs.google.com/document/d/11ePx7cP-M49rBVtF4gvaMBA02ZH92W5xOK5DXOzdH9Q/edit
Merged letter 2: docs.google.com/document/d/1to3zGwJYsBflIeiOm9pydNOdmQ9IJDXxbtNADEsylkA/edit
```

like from this angle it looks like my code has run perfectly fine but then. I visit the links and it asks for me to request access even though, I performed all the previous steps using the same Gmail account (i.e. built all the credentials using the same Gmail account, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your following situation,

> like from this angle it looks like my code has run perfectly fine but then. I visit the links and it asks for me to request access even though, I performed all the previous steps using the same Gmail account (i.e. built all the credentials using the same Gmail account, etc.).

I understood that the script works without errors. And, about `it asks for me to request access`, when I saw your showing script, it seems that you are using the service account. And, the template file is copied using the service account. About `the same Gmail account`, if this is your Google account, the service account is different from your Google account. I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue.

In this case, it is required to add permission for accessing from your Google account. When this is reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```py
def _copy_template(tmpl_id, source, service):
    """(private) Copies letter template document using Drive API then
        returns file ID of (new) copy.
    """
    try:
        body = {'name': 'Merged form letter (%s)' % source}
        return service.files().copy(body=body, fileId=tmpl_id,
                                    fields='id').execute().get('id')
    except HttpError as error:
        print(f"An error occurred: {error}")
        return error
```

#### To:

```py
def _copy_template(tmpl_id, source, service):
    """(private) Copies letter template document using Drive API then
        returns file ID of (new) copy.
    """
    try:
        body = {'name': 'Merged form letter (%s)' % source}
        copiedFileId = service.files().copy(body=body, fileId=tmpl_id, fields='id').execute().get('id')
        permission = {
            "type": "user",
            "role": "writer",
            "emailAddress": "###" # <--- Please set your gmail of your account.
        }
        res = service.permissions().create(fileId=copiedFileId, body=permission).execute()
        return copiedFileId

    except HttpError as error:
        print(f"An error occurred: {error}")
        return error
```

- By this modification, after the template file was copied, your account is added to the permission of the copied file as a writer.

#### Note:

- As another approach, when the copied file is created to the specific folder in your Google Drive of your account, you have permission automatically to the copied file when the template file is copied. In that case, please share your folder with the service account. And, please modify your `_copy_template` as follows.

  - From

    ```
      body = {'name': 'Merged form letter (%s)' % source}
    ```
  - To

    ```
      body = {'name': 'Merged form letter (%s)' % source, 'parents': ['###folderId###']}
    ```

#### References:

- [Method: permissions.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/permissions/create)
- [Method: files.copy](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/copy)

Comment: It works thank you very much!!! I went with the second option,

Comment: @Baker Ssebandeke Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.